Error after copying template in 2sxc Coursesandevents app
When copying a template in the coursesandevents app of 2sxc. We are getting an error :
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'AppCode' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
while we are using the exact same code of the original file : live/List.cshtml
What are we missing?
we are currently using version:
DNN: 09.11.00
2Sxc: v18.0.0
Coursesandevents v6.17.1
We created a new view, and copied the exact same template code of List.cshtml

Can you provide more context? How/where are you editing the file you copied? How did you copy the View? Did you (Copilot) regenerate the Data and Views?

Also, I highly recommend getting current on DNN, unless you've already tried and experienced a problem, v9.11.x to v9.13.04 (latest) should be very smooth upgrade. While you are at it, 2sxc v18.02.00 includes a lot of fixes, so that is also recommended! As always, backup first.

Best update to latest 2sxc v18.02 - the AppCode is still being improved and maybe there was a bug.
